# in HTML form specified array keys replaced with sequential keys in PHP $_POST array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, post

I have a HTML form which includes a table where each row is an database entry and has it's own input fields and buttons. I use array notation (e.g. `name="edit[<?php echo $entry['id']; ?>]"`) with the entry's id as key to determine in PHP which entry should be edited/deleted.

thats the HTML form and two example rows:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="index.php" method="POST" name="foo_form">
...
<tr>
  <td>14</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="input" placeholder="fooooo" name="headline[14]" value="fooooo"/></td>
  <td><textarea class="input-block-level" rows="2" name="text[14]">lorem ipsum123</textarea></td>
  <td>
    <input name="edit[14]" type="submit" class="btn" value="save changes"/>
    <input name="delete[14]" type="submit" class="btn" value="delete"/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>15</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="input" placeholder="baaar" name="headline[15]" value="baaar"/></td>
  <td><textarea class="input-block-level" rows="2" name="text[15]">lorem ipsum456</textarea></td>
  <td>
    <input name="edit[15]" type="submit" class="btn" value="save changes"/>
    <input name="delete[15]" type="submit" class="btn" value="delete"/>
  </td>
</tr>
...
</form>
```

Lets say I press the delete button of the entry with id 15 then this is the `var_dump($_POST)` output which I get on my developement server at home (PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8) and on my hosted vServer (PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.21):

```
array(3) {
  ["headline"]=>
  array(2) {
    [14]=>
    string(6) "fooooo"
    [15]=>
    string(5) "baaar"
  }
  ["text"]=>
  array(2) {
    [14]=>
    string(14) "lorem ipsum123"
    [15]=>
    string(14) "lorem ipsum456"
  }
  ["delete"]=>
  array(1) {
    [15]=>
    string(6) "delete"
  }
}
```

And thats what I get on a shared webspace (PHP Version 5.3.27) where the script has to run. The correct id's as array keys are missing and I get 0, 1, ...n as array keys:

```
array(3) {
  ["headline"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "fooooo"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "baaar"
  }
  ["text"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "lorem ipsum123"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "lorem ipsum456"
  }
  ["delete"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "delete"
  }
}
```

The files are exactly the same and the HTML form does contain the right array keys. I checked the sent POST request with firebug, it contains the correct keys, too. There must be a serverside setting or something which disables the specified keys and replaces it with sequential keys. Hope someone knows a solution.

Comment: Do you have suhosin installed on that shared webspace?

Comment: that was one of my first thoughts, but `phpinfo()` says there is no suhosin on the shared space where the problem appears. (I have suhosin on the vServer, where all works fine)